# How to apply ifelse statement in mutate_if

Tags: r, dplyr

I have over 2000 columns of data that should be dummy coded. But, there are occasional instances where the value is greater than 1. So, I'd like to mutate all of these columns at once and convert anything greater than 1 to 1. Here's a snippet of what the data looks like with the first few columns.

I've tried using `mutate_if` and I think it is still the best option for what I need since I only need to `mutate` the numeric "code" columns. But, I can't get the syntax right...

```
    # the data
    d <- tibble(
      recordID = c("ID1", "ID2", "ID1", "ID4"),
      personNumber = c("1", "1", "2", "1"),
      code_1 =  c(0, 0, 1, 1),
      code_2 = c(0, 2, 0, 0),  # this 2 should be a 1
      code_3 = c(0, 0, 1, 2),  # this 2 should be a 1
      code_4 = c(0, 1, 0, 2)   # this 2 should be a 1
    )

    # what it looks like
    d
    # A tibble: 4 x 6
      recordID personNumber code_1 code_2 code_3 code_4
      <chr>    <chr>         <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
    1 ID1      1                 0      0      0      0
    2 ID2      1                 0      2      0      1   # this 2 should be a 1
    3 ID1      2                 1      0      1      0
    4 ID4      1                 1      0      3      2   # this 3 & 2 should be 1
```

Here is my attempt and what the output should look like:

```
    # my attempt
    d %>%
        mutate_if(is.numeric, ifelse(. >= 1, 1, 0))   # doesn't work


    # what it should look like
    d
    # A tibble: 4 x 6
      recordID personNumber code_1 code_2 code_3 code_4
      <chr>    <chr>         <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
    1 ID1      1                 0      0      0      0
    2 ID2      1                 0      1      0      1   # 2 has been replaced
    3 ID1      2                 1      0      1      0
    4 ID4      1                 1      0      1      1   # 3 & 2 have been replaced
```

Comment: The underlying question is how to supply a function with arguments inside `mutate_if` (same applies to `mutate_all`, `summarize_if`, etc), which is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49764273/5325862)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, there is no need for using `ifelse()`. The result of any comparison is a TRUE/FALSE logical vector, than can be converted into a vector of integers:

```
d %>%
 mutate_if(is.numeric, ~ +(. >= 1))

  recordID personNumber code_1 code_2 code_3 code_4
  <chr>    <chr>         <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>
1 ID1      1                 0      0      0      0
2 ID2      1                 0      1      0      1
3 ID1      2                 1      0      1      0
4 ID4      1                 1      0      1      1
```

Or:

```
d %>%
 mutate_if(is.numeric, ~ (. >= 1) * 1)
```

Comment: This is great! Though, I'm curious to learn about what the "~ +" pats of the code are accomplishing.

Comment: `+` is essentially doing the same as `as.integer()` in the post from akrun. It converts a logical vector into a numeric vector. `~` is called tilde operator and it allows to create a formula.

Answer (score 1):

We can coerce the logical to binary with `as.integer`

```
d %>% 
     mutate_if(is.numeric, ~ as.integer(. >= 1))
# A tibble: 4 x 6
#  recordID personNumber code_1 code_2 code_3 code_4
#  <chr>    <chr>         <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>
#1 ID1      1                 0      0      0      0
#2 ID2      1                 0      1      0      1
#3 ID1      2                 1      0      1      0
#4 ID4      1                 1      0      1      1
```